# Python __iter__ and __repr__ what they doing?

Tags: python

I am currently working on LinkedList and I have the following code and I don't understand what the `__iter__` and `__repr__` are doing exactly?

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
        self.next = None

class LinkedList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None

    def append(self, value):
        if self.head is None:
            self.head = Node(value)
            return

        node = self.head
        while node.next:
            node = node.next

        node.next = Node(value)

    def __iter__(self):
        node = self.head
        while node:
            yield node.value
            node = node.next

    def __repr__(self):
        return str([v for v in self])
```

Here I am creating the LinkedList and append the values at the end of my list.

```
llist = LinkedList()
for value in [4,2,5,1,-3,0]:
    llist.append(value)
```

If I print the list `print(llist)` then I am getting `[4, 2, 5, 1, -3, 0]`

I guess this is coming from `__iter__` and `__repr__`. What I don't understand is when my `__iter__` and `__repr__` starts and which is running first? How can I print objects  outside my class?

Comment: Given you implemented this yourself (?), I'm a bit surprised that you do not understand why you are iterating over self in `__repr__`.

Answer (score 1):

From my limited understanding of Python internals, when you `print()` an object, the `str()` function is called on it. This function probably knows how to format some kinds of objects, such as strings and numbers, for others, it calls their `__repr__()` method which is supposed to return a string. So `__repr__()` is called first.

The `__repr__()` method was written by the developer to return a normal list representation which is created by the list comprehension `[v for v in self]`. The iteration ultimately calls the `__iter__()` method which is a generator function (as indicated by the use of `yield`). This function iterates over the elements of the list, and every `yield` makes one element available to the `for ... in ...` construct.

Comment: If I for example do reversedList = reverse(llist) outside the class and print(reversedList) then I am getting <main.object...>. How can I print this now in human readable way

Comment: Where does the `reverse()` function come from? It apparently creates something that isn't a LinkedList, so it naturally behaves and prints differently.

Answer (score 0):

[Read the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#special-method-names).

**iter**: defines on what attribute/how iterating on a class' object is supposed to work - e.g. what is "next". If you wanted say to iterate on animals, and you wanted the iteration to be defined by each animal's weight, then you could use self.weight in your animal class much in the way that you're using self.value right now....

_ *repr* _: When you do print(my_Object), Python by default has a representation (repr) defined. You can re-define using this function.

Answer (score 0):

when you are implementing the **iter** method, you are changing the behaviour of looping throught your list.

what I mean is in the normal for loop when you call:

```
for l in list:
   print(l)
```

this what will happen behind the scene :

```
# create an iterator object from that iterable
iter_obj = iter(list)
# infinite loop
while True:
    try:
        # get the next item
        element = next(iter_obj)
        # do something with element
    except StopIteration:
        # if StopIteration is raised, break from loop
        break
```

so if you redefine the **iter** function inside your linked list class you are redefining the iteration function and what should iterating through your iterator returns.

same basically for **repr** you redefine the represantation of your object. for example when you call print(obj) you get the obj printed but you can change it to the format you want to if you implement **repr** correctly as you wish.

take a look here for more explaination:
 https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/iterator
[https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/**str**-vs-__repr](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/__str__-vs-__repr)

Comment: If I for example reverse the list outside the class then I am getting <__main__.Node object at 0x7ff3e5265850>. How can I print this object then?

Answer (score 0):

`__iter__` represents the iterator method of the class. Let's understand through code:

```
llist = LinkedList()
for value in [4,2,5,1,-3,0]:
    llist.append(value)
for value in llist:
    print(value)
```

Output

```
4
2
5
1
-3
0
```

Here, when we take the object as an iterator, `__iter__()` method would be into action which iterates and traverse linked list and yields node values.

```
print(llist)
```

Output

```
[4, 2, 5, 1, -3, 0]
```

Here, `__repr__()` method would be into action and would print node values as specified in the code.